# Swift & UITextFieldDelegate: How to get object that called the delegate? Or call textbox with variable?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to create my first app in XCode and Swift. Nothing major, just a simple calculator for a game I play often. Would be handy for me lol.

It simply is supposed to have 6 text boxes, each box is the number of materials I have. You can "combine" the materials. 4 level 1 materials combines to 1 level 2 material, and so on up to level 6.

I could have 1 level 1, 3 level 2, 1 level 3, 0 level 4, 3 level 5, 1 level 6.. I would put each one in a text box, hit the button, and it will tell me how many more level 1 materials I need to get another level 6.

Anyways, following the guide here,  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html, it has you manually defining the text box. However, I have 6, and I find it terrible to have to define each one manually. What if I had a huge app with 100 text boxes, ridiculous.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var txt1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txt2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txt3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txt4: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txt5: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txt6: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnGo: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        txt1.delegate = self
        txt2.delegate = self
        txt3.delegate = self
        txt4.delegate = self
        txt5.delegate = self
        txt6.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        // here is where its dumb
        txt1.text = textField.text
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func calculateItems(sender: UIButton) {
        // do my calculations
    }


}
```

As you can see in `func textFieldDidEndEditing`, this wont work. I read a tip to assign tags to each input. Still, I would have to manually account for each one like so:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if (textField.tag == 1) {
            txt1.text = textField.text
        }

        if (textField.tag == 2) {
            txt2.text = textField.text
        }

        if (textField.tag == 3) {
            txt3.text = textField.text
        }

        if (textField.tag == 4) {
            txt4.text = textField.text
        }

        if (textField.tag == 5) {
            txt5.text = textField.text
        }

        if (textField.tag == 6) {
            txt6.text = textField.text
        }
    }
```

Again, this seems pretty dumb that everyone does it like this..

**What I Need**

Either

**A)** to be able to call the text field by a variable

```
var dynText = textField
dynText.text = textField.text
```

However, this throws an error saying variable dynText doesn't have a member of text.

**B)** to know which object (text box) hit/called the delegate in the first place.

How can I solve this? I doubt you guys are manually defining each and every text box in your apps!

Comment: Why do your want to assign text to the textfield that has just ended editing?When this delegate is called, the text entered by the user is already present in that textfield.

Comment: The textfields you receive in delegate methods are the ones that called the delegate method.ex in textFieldDidEndEditing you received same textfield for which the corresponding action occurred.you don't need to check the tags and assign values as you have done.

Comment: There are many reasons why you would need to update the textbox the user just filled. For example: convert "joe smith" to "Joe Smith" or to remove extra spaces with trim() or remove invalid characters. -- I just want to update the text box without manually defining 100s of them manually.